# Return value from custom swing components to parent class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have the main class named `myapp` of my applicaion that has a jLayeredPane.

I have a class named `mycustompanel` that extends jpanel.

In `myapp` I have a method that adds several `mycustompanel` objects in the jLayeredPane. The number of `mycustompanel`s added is not fixed.

The `mycustompanel` has a property named `personsurname` that is given a value when `mycustompanel` is added to the jLayeredPane.

`mycustompanel` has this listener:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
    if(evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
    answer=personsurname;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,answer);    
    }  
    }
```

where answer is defined as a public String. So I can see the value of the `personsurname` of the clicked `mycustompanel`.

What I want is to get the answer value to `myapp`.

I think I should add a method like

`public String getAnswer() { return answer; }`

to the `mycustompanel` , but how do I call this method from the main class, so that each time a `mycustompanel` is clicked the `personsurname` value of the specific item that is clicked gets to the `myapp` class?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm as far as I understand it you could write a setPersonSurnameInMyapp method in MyApp.
so everytime the mouseevent is called you call that method and save the value in a variable in Myapp?